# Identifying items in store

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I`m working on a problem that involves identyfying same items represented differently, for example "apple iphone 4g black" and "iphone 4g", etc. The data can be very noisy, and items like "iphone 4g black 16gb" and "iphone 4g 8gb" are different. What i have right now is a database of items of store A, that has a string nomenclature of an item and some features like model, category(for example, phone) and price. I also have a database of items from other stores, say B and C. For items from B and C i only know price.

What i would like to do is find identical items from database A in databases B and C.

Is this a well known area of research? What i have in mind right now is encoding strings as 3 or 4 grams, then using database of store A to train classifiers to identify category, model, etc. And then use it to classify items from stores B and C. The problem is a lot of information from other stores can be very corrupted or ommited, and things like "iphone 4g 8gb" and "iphone 4g 4gb" are different while "cool black smartphone apple 4g 8gb" and "iphone 4gb 8gb" are the same. Also, some items that are present in store A might be not present in stores B and C and vice versa.